# Por qué mi app a partir de Android 9 no conecta a base de datos externa?

Tags: mysql, android

Tengo una app desarrollada en Android Studio, [image: Este es mi gradle]

Resulta que, en principio la tenía conectada a un host gratuito y la conexión a la base de datos funcionaba en todos los dispositivos, pero a partir de Android 9 al momento de registrarse, te registraba y te sacaba de la app. Luego volvías a entrar y funcionaba normal. Pero ahora la he conectado a un dominio nuevo (con hosting de paga) y funciona perfecto hasta Android 8. A partir de 9 directamente no conecta a la base de datos, no muestra datos.

Comment: Qué error te marca al momento de realizar la conexión?

Comment: Parece que estás usando librerías de firebase antiguas, que muy posiblemente ya no funcionen en Android más modernos. Te lo está avisando al pintar de amarillo las librerías.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio recuerda realizar tu  pregunta en base a [ask] , agrega detalles que permitan ayudarte¿Como  creas la BD?